# Why does CodePen script not work with my NextJS local server?

Tags: javascript, next.js, codepen

Before anything, keep in mind I am extremely new to both NextJS, CodePen, and web dev in general.

I found this cool mouse movement animation on CodePen and wanted to implement it onto the website I just started building on NextJS. I'm fairly certain I imported the files correctly and the CSS works however the script does not.

[The CodePen script I'm trying to use.](https://codepen.io/MarcoGuglielmelli/pen/ExGYae)

This is my entire *index.js* code.

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Script from 'next/script'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <html lang="en" >
    <Head>
          
      <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
      
      <title>CodePen - Animated Background</title>
      <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200,400,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css"/>
      <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://www.marcoguglie.it/Codepen/AnimatedHeaderBg/demo-1/css/demo.css'/><link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/dynamic.css"/>

    </Head>
    <body>

      <div id="large-header" className="large-header">
        <canvas id="demo-canvas"></canvas>
          <h1 className="main-title">Vansh <span className="thin">Sharma</span></h1>
      </div>

      <Script src='https://www.marcoguglie.it/Codepen/AnimatedHeaderBg/demo-1/js/EasePack.min.js'/>
      <Script src='https://www.marcoguglie.it/Codepen/AnimatedHeaderBg/demo-1/js/rAF.js'/>
      <Script src='https://www.marcoguglie.it/Codepen/AnimatedHeaderBg/demo-1/js/TweenLite.min.js'/>
      <Script src="../scripts/dynamic_script.js" strategy='beforeInteractive' defer={false} type='text/javascript'/>

    </body>
    </html>

  )
}
```

Comment: Have you tried importing the whole codepen source code and linking it into your script??

Comment: @AlvinCHENG That is what I did, I downloaded the source code file from that given pen. Unless you mean downloading the source code for the dependencies as well. That being said I also forgot to link the Pen I was using so I'll include that in the original post as well.